# Python dynamodb ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid key: Syntax error; key:

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

Trying to do an update_item which is supposed to create new attributes if it doesn't find existing ones (according to documentation) but I am getting a Sytax error.

I have been wracking my brain all day trying to figure out why I am getting this and I can't seem to get past this.  Thank you for any help

Error I am getting:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation:
   ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: "var4"
```

MyCode:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('contacts')
    table.update_item(
    Key={'email': emailID},
    UpdateExpression=SET last_name = :var0, address_1_state = :var1, email_2 = :var2, phone = :var3, phone_2 = :var4

    ExpressionAttributeValues={
     'var0': 'Metzger', 
     'var1': 'CA', 
     'var2': 'none', 
     'var3': '949 302-9072', 
     'var4': '818-222-2311'
    }
    )
```

Comment: did you modify your code section after the answer was posted? the answer code looks identical to the code given in the question...

Comment: The change was in the key names. For example from 'var0' to ':var0' (added the two dots)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

just change the section like the following -

```
 ExpressionAttributeValues={
     ':var0': 'Metzger', 
     ':var1': 'CA', 
     ':var2': 'none', 
     ':var3': '949 302-9072', 
     ':var4': '818-222-2311'
    }
```

Hope the code will work then :)